# slapcat -n 1 -l users.ldif slapcat: database doesn't support necessary operations

Tags: openldap

I am getting the error

```
slapcat: database doesn't support necessary operations.
```

When trying to run the command

```
slapcat -n 1 -l users.ldif
```

replacing the 1 for a 0 works and to my understanding that will be my config backup.

Can anyone help me understand why i get this error and what to do about it to allow me to migrate my ldap to a new server?

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not 100% sure on this, I believe it has to do with what you set your database to when creating it. At least in my case since I have olcDatabase set to {2} when I changed n to 2 it worked... whereby I then saw my users in the users.ldif file.

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
```

In my case I had the same error and changed it to

```
slapcat -n 2 -l users.ldif
```